# Seria correto utilizar uma classe estática para consumir um web service?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, web-service

Uma dúvida que de vez enquanto surge quando estou programando é relacionada a utilização de classes estáticas.

A [documentação oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) da Microsoft diz o seguinte a respeito de classes estáticas:

> A static class can be used as a convenient container for sets of
>   methods that just operate on input parameters and do not have to get
>   or set any internal instance fields.

Então, aqui diz que classes estáticas podem ser usadas como um container para métodos que apenas operam em parâmetros de entrada e que não precisam de trabalhar com campos de instâncias.

Vamos então a um problema mais específico. Minha aplicação ASP.NET consome um web service que irá me retornar informações relativas ao negócio. Para consumir o web service eu devo fazer a autenticação juntamente com o mesmo, e após isso enviar requisições HTTP, simples, para isso então criei uma classe, que vou chamar aqui de `ApiClient`.

Em nenhum momento do processo eu preciso acessar recursos de instância da classe `ApiClient`, levando em consideração que dados como URL de endpoint, chave de acesso e período de validade da chave de acesso serão os mesmos para todos os que consumirem os métodos da classe `ApiClient`.

Até aí imagino que a escolha em user uma classe estática esteja correta. Minha dúvida é a seguinte, em caso de múltiplas chamadas simultâneas de um método da classe `ApiClient`, caso uma requisição demore digamos, 5 segundos, essas requisições seriam enfileiradas, fazendo com que a classe estática se torne um gargalo no consumo do web service?

Segue abaixo um exemplo da classe `ApiClient` que tentei descrever.

```
public static class ApiClient
{
    private static string baseUri = "http://baseuri.com";

    private static async Task<string> GetKey()
    {
        //Get the key
    }

    private static async Task<string> SendRequest(string resource)
    {
        string key = await GetKey();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", key);

        string url = $"{baseUri}{resource}";
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result;
    }

    public static async Task<CustomerInfo> GetCustomerInfo(string customerId)
    {
        string resource = $"/api/method/{customerId}";
        string json = await SendRequest(resource);
        CustomerInfo customerInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerInfo>(json);
        return customerInfo;
    }       
}
```

Essa abordagem poderia ser considerada problemática? Nesse caso eu teria problema gargalo caso múltiplas requisições sejam passadas para o método `SendRequest`? Se sim esse problema poderia ser solucionado com a mudança de abordagem e criação de instâncias da classe `ApiClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, de fato eu considero uma abordagem correta. Se atende suas necessidades eu não tenho como dizer. Quem defende OOP já dizer que não pode fazer isto, quem é pragmático à princípio não vê problemas. Quem acha que nenhum código pode ser escrito se não tiver testes vai dizer que não dá pra testar, quem é pragmático sabe que só impõe uma técnica diferente, se testes formais estão de fato sendo feitos.

Não há diferença de execução de métodos estáticos ou de instância. A única diferença entre eles é que o método de instância recebe um parâmetro extra oculto chamado `this`. Não existe um método diferente para cada instância, existe apenas um para toda a aplicação, portanto sua execução simultânea é igual ao método estático. A instância tem estado individual, mas o comportamento sempre pertence à classe, mesmo que dê a impressão que de ser diferente.

Você pode ter problemas com o `SendRequest()` se ele conter problema de concorrência, o que não dá para avaliar com o que foi colocado, não não é que poderia criar gargalo, é que poderia acessar dois recursos ao mesmo tempo que não podem ser acessados ao mesmo tempo, então exigiria uma coordenação. Mas isto é hipotético, nada indica que seja o caso.

Eu só tornaria `baseUri` `readonly` e eliminaria variáveis desnecessárias.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @bigown, poderia elaborar um pouco a parte das variáveis desnecessárias?

Comment: Só a `client` é de fato necessária, todas as outras são usadas apenas uma vez, então não tem porque existir, se deve eliminar todas depende de estilo de codificação, mas algumas não fazem o menor sentido. Na verdade talve\ eu eliminaria `baseUri`, só não falei porque pode ser que vá usar em algum outro lugar. Mas se manter, não descartaria até mesmo transformá-la em `const`.